# Хранить id как строку

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Не знаю где правильно задать такой вопрос, если метку выбрал неправильно, пожалуйста, поправьте.

Как вы считаете, правильно ли хранить id чего-либо в переменной типа string? Неважно в каком языке программирования. Ведь это поле зачастую используется именно как строка (вставка в запрос БД, вывод на экран, итд), математических действий с id никаких не производится. Да, это ест значительно больше памяти. Но это также лишает необходимости постоянного преобразования типов, что делает код немного чище и возможно быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Более правильный вариант завести отдельный тип для этого, а возможно и несколько разных типов.

Что это дает:

1. Проверка типов - вы случайно не передадите неправильный объект
2. Улучшение читаемости программы - по типу будет понятно, что это не просто строка
3. Дополнительная функциональность - вы можете добавить к типу нужные вам методы, а строки в некоторых языках представлены типом который нельзя расширять

В некоторых библиотеках уже есть подобные типы, например [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) в Java.